# 2008 Dodge Avenger 4 cylinder

Tags: dodge, acceleration, avenger

My car sputters when I accelerate and my rpm keeps jumping. I put it on the machine at my mechanic and it doesn't show anything wrong with the car. I checked my motor and transmission and its nothing wrong what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Clean up the throttle, body most of the time if there isn't any codes or check engine light is that your problem, but be carefully when do it, because if it is an electric throttle if you clean it incorrectly you can put it out of calibration, hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Also clean maf sensor if it has one